# Meaning of 'born' in this sentence

Tags: meaning

I appreciate your help to explain the meaning of the word 'born' in this sentence:

> Kites were invented in China, where materials suitable for kite building were readily available. The silk fabric was found to be best for making the sail of a kite. It is **born** a lightweight material and an asthetically pleasing one.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a little Googling shows that this is from a Korean exam: in the original sentence a blank appears where the OP has *born*, and the word appears only in the key. I'm virtually certain that *born* is a typo--it should be *both*.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence

> It is **born** a lightweight material and an asthetically pleasing one.

which is incorrect, you may mean

> It is **borne of** a lightweight material and an asthetically pleasing one.

which is an *archaic* expression, or

> It is **born from** a lightweight material and an asthetically pleasing one.

both meaning "**to be composed of**" or "**produced from**", since it is referring to "*silk fabric*" in the previous sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider "It is born a lightweight material" as not grammatically correct. "It is born of a lightweight material" would mean it was made with a lightweight material.

Born meaning "brought into existence". It was brought into existence from a lightweight material.

Still an odd word choice in my experience (fluent American English).

Comment: It is odd, and almost certainly a mistake: see my comment below the question.

Answer (score 0):

The use of **born** is not the correct word to use in this context.
Born is the past tense form of bear which relates to childbirth.
Ex. The child was born on 2017. (Passive verb)

I think the writer is trying to say the following:
It is **made of** a lightweight material.

> Blockquote

I hope that helps.